# Console Application to bulk create or update records

Tags: c#, console-application

I am running a console application to Create or Update the records into TableB by looping through all the records(approximately 250000 records) in TableA. But I want to know how to continue if my console application failed in between...Which happened twice up to now and I keep on removing the records and started again.

Could anyone please suggest me how I continue running the console app from where I left, if I have GUID of record where my process failed.

Comment: What is your persistence storage? Do you use an ORM in order to achieve the behavior? Please share some code.

The answer will probably be - DB commit in chunks (of say 100 records) - but we can't help you with specific code if you don't share yours.

Comment: You know about try/catch, right?

Comment: Well. I am writing it actually on CRM table. But the concept is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save Guid of migrated objects in file or another storage. Then filter data from table A and migrate only failed objects.

This is pseudocode:

```
var dataFromTableA = GetDataFromTableA();
var importedObjectGuids = GetImportedObjectsGuidFormFile();

var filterdData = new List<your_object>();
foreach(var data in dataFromTableA)
{
    if (importedObjectGuids.Contains(data.Guid)) continue;

    filterdData.Add(data);
}

foreach (var data in filterdData)
{
    try
    {
        Migrate(data);
        SaveMigrationResult(data.Guid);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {   Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You - @Markeli. That gave some idea to go forward and actually I am writing to CRM database table but the concept is same. I will try to accomplish it. Many Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to solve this would be not to fail or to recover from the error.

If you wan't to keep track of your progress you could simply write the GUID you are currently working at to a file.

```
File.WriteAllText("tmp.txt", GUID.ToString());
```

You can afterwards read the GUID from this file.

You could also use Application Settings to store the last GUID.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi SirBirne, Thank you for your reply. I am able to write the GUID to the temp file and now I want to know how I could continue from where process failed. I looked at the link but it doesn't make any clue to me. Please suggest